# How to extract files from an unrooted android (GT-N7000) which is stuck in boot logo?

Tags: android, backup, adb

I have a Samsung Galaxy note (1) which is stuck in boot logo when I turn it on. I can access Android recovery mode, and have tried wiping cache data and do a normal boot, but it didn't work. I'm trying to avoid factory setting reset before getting hands on data inside and saving them. I've tried to backup through adb backup command but it didn't work. adb does not give me permission to access data on data folder. I've also tried to update firmware in download mode using kies but it does not have it for GT-N7000.

P.S.: I've got a new battery but still the same.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've included that in description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do "adb pull /data" hoepfully that should work, if not, report it here :).